File uploads get corrupted when reading a POST request body
I'm building an android app that needs to receive a file from a web application.
I'm using Java ServerSocket to deal with that.
I handled the POST request headers and all works fine but when I write the file to disk it gets corrupted.
I displayed the first few bytes of both the original and the corrupted file to see what bytes were written wrong and I have no clue how to deal with it.

I use this code to read the part of the POST request which contains the file data util I get the boundary string.
I prefixed the boundary string with "\r\n" because I don't want that included in my file especially when it's not part of it.
// Handle POST request


File file_upload = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Download/" + filename);
if (file_upload.createNewFile()) {
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file_upload)));

    // boundary index
    int bi = 0;
    // char
    int c;

    // this is boundary prefixed with \r\n--
    String __boundary = "\r\n--" + boundary;

    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

    // `br` is BufferedReader
    // I start reading the file content here. br.read() reads the first byte and keeps reading until it meets the boundary.
    
    while ((c = br.read()) != -1) {
        if ((char) c == __boundary.charAt(bi)) {
            buffer.append((char) c);
            bi++;
            if (bi == __boundary.length()) {
                break;
            }
        } else {
            if (buffer.length() != 0) {
                out.write(buffer.toString());
                buffer.setLength(0);
            } else {
                bi = 0;
            }
            out.write((char) c);
        }
    }
    out.close();
}


You are writing a binary file as a string? that is probably corrupting the output.

Why are you using home-brewed multipart parsing? That's not advisable

You're reading the stream as if it were text. It's not - it's a PNG, so binary data. It should be treated as binary data. You may need to detect the boundary using the bytes of \r\n-- with an assumption of a particular character encoding, but other than that, you should read and write the data as text - no BufferedWriter, no BufferedReader, just InputStream and OutputStream-based classes.
(If you can change your approach to requests and responses so that each request/response only contains one file of data, that would avoid you having to look at the boundary at all. We don't really have enough context to know whether that's feasible, but it seems unlikely that you should have to do boundary detection in your code - even if you need to use multi-part requests and responses, I'd expect an HTTP client to handle that for you.)

Yes, I only do one file per request. Can I depend on the content length from the headers and then subtract the length of the part headers and the length of the boundary string from it. Is it the best practice ?

@Ammar: It's not clear why you're using ServerSocket at all... or why you'd use that to receive a file from a web application. (Normally you'd use an HTTP client to make a request to a web application.) Basically, I'd strongly advise against you trying to implement HTTP yourself - pretty much whatever you're trying to do with HTTP, there's bound to be a tried and tested library to do it for you.

All of this code is a part of an android app that sends and receive files using the web. It hosts an HTML document from which you can upload files to the device. When someone upload a file I want to achieve thoose.
1- I want to stream the file to disk without loading all of its content to RAM (this will help with large files)
2- I want to get  the progress of file upload to show in app

@Ammar: Again, I don't think implementing an HTTP server yourself is likely to be a good idea. (Opening up a port to the outside world doesn't seem like a good idea either mind you. I would want to keep everything controlled by the app, using the app as a client at all times, but anyway...) At this point I've explained why your code is corrupting the data, and given you multiple alternatives (using streams instead of reader/writer, and ideally avoiding implementing HTTP yourself entirely). I think that's all that's required for your post.
